# OpenMP enforce the order in which tasks are created

Tags: c, openmp, hpc, multicore

I am new to OpenMP and think my use case is not simple - hence looking for pointers on approach.

Is there a way to enforce execution of tasks in order they are spawned in OpenMP?

What I want to achieve is as follows

My data is a packet of data which contains a sequence number and sensor id.

The order of sequence number must be maintained for each sensor id but different sensor ids can execute in parallel.

In pseudo code - so please excuse the syntax. I am seeking conceptual understanding.

```
#pragma parallel for ordered 
for data in data_packet_by_sequence

#pragma task nowait
   omp_set_lock(data.sensor_id)
   process_data(data) // must execute in order of data.sequence 
   omp_unset_lock(data.sensor_id)
```

But the problem is that the process data might be schedule in a sequence that does not honor the sequence number of the packet

How can I enforce that when a sensor data is processed, it respects the data.sequence ordering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, there is probably a simple solution without tasks, assuming the number of iterations is predictable: is it the case?

Comment: No the iterations are not predictable.  The data_packet_by_sequence  will have varied sizes. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: No, I mean once you decide to process a `data_packet_by_sequence`, do some new data arrive and are appended to *this one* while you are processing it or not?

Comment: No that wont be the case. The data in data_packet_by_sequence  is already know. In Objective C there are constructs NSOperationsQueue and NSOperation (aka Task) but not able to find anything like so here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `depend` clause is a solution. I should rather write a comment because I am not really sure this works and is a proper answer, but writing (pseudo-)code in comments is difficult...

```
int dep[nbsensors];

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single nowait
{
    for data in data_packet_by_sequence {
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(...) depend(inout:dep[data.sensor_id])
        process_data(data);
    }
}
```

Explanation: when a task that has a `depend(out:x)` clause is running, it prevents all other tasks with a `depend(in:x)` clause to start. As a consequence, among the tasks having a `depend(inout:x)` clause (same x for all of them), only one of them can run at a given time.

You don't even need to actually write something in `dep[]`.

Comment: Thanks, but how will this enforce scheduling by the order of data.sequence_number for a single sensor_id as for each sensor_id, tasks can technically be scheduled independent of the data.sequence_number which is not part of the depend. Even if we can add it depend clause. still I dont know if the sequence is preserved. Ideally we need a task queue per sensor_id and the scheduler picks from this list parallelly across sensor_id but I dont know how to declare it in openMP.

Comment: I think I am looking for parallel FIFO task queues - where each thread picks of the tasks off the queue in order of arrival - but multiple FIFO queues work in parallel.

Comment: Did you try?? Normally the original order should be preserved for a given sensor, at least this is how I think it should work. The tasks enter sequentially, and the scheduler can analyse the dependencies.

If you don't give a try to proposed solutions just because "you're not sure", what can I say? Do you want me to write a full code and test it for you?

Comment: Hmm - good point. Let me try first. I undestand it now. Dumb me.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very simple solution, where all the threads execute the whole loop, but a given thread processes only some selected sensors:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int nbthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    for data in data_packet_by_sequence {
        if ((data.sensor_id*nbthreads)/nbsensors == ithread) 
           process_data(data);
    }
}
```

This garantees that all the data from a given sensor are processed sequentially by the same thread